# grepl works in one case but not another?

Tags: r

I have 2 functions in a personal R package I made. It is basically to clean a list of URLs I pulled off a website, including only keeping URLS containing the query entered into the function. One of the functions works fine (these are just one piece of the function giving me trouble):

```
url_list <- data.frame(url_list) %>%
    filter(grepl(query, url_list)) %>%
    filter(!grepl(remove.list, url_list)) %>%
    unique()
```

However, for another function that does the same thing but for another website, I have had to create separate data.frames for each page of results due to how the website shows results. I then rbind them together, then use the same function but it yields nothing at all in the final df despite there being rows of URLs that should have remained. I cannot figure out what could be wrong here because it's the same formula!

```
url_list <- data.frame(url_list) %>%
    filter(grepl(query, url_list)) %>%
    filter(!grepl(remove.list, url_list)) %>%
    unique()
```

Here is the data frame I am trying to filter.

Meaning of some variables:

`query <- 'brownies'`
**I think the issue is with `query`, because after running it, it does not filter out anything, where it should only leave rows that contain `query`, in this case, `brownies`**

`remove.list <- paste(c("/gallery/", "/article/", "/tag/"), collapse = '|')`

```
structure(list(. = c("https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/gluten-free-fudgy-sweet-potato-brownies/", 
"/tag/baking-therapy/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/gluten-free-fudgy-sweet-potato-brownies/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/one-bowl-cocoa-brownies/", 
"/tag/dessert/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/one-bowl-cocoa-brownies/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/article/our-best-bars-squares-recipes/", 
"/tag/baking/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/article/our-best-bars-squares-recipes/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/this-impressive-12-layer-chocolate-cake-is-made-with-a-single-pan/", 
"/tag/baking-therapy/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/this-impressive-12-layer-chocolate-cake-is-made-with-a-single-pan/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/these-easy-sourdough-discard-crackers-come-together-with-just-5-ingredients/", 
"/tag/baking-therapy/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/these-easy-sourdough-discard-crackers-come-together-with-just-5-ingredients/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/turkish-coffee-brownies/", 
"/tag/girl-meets-farm/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/turkish-coffee-brownies/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/celebrate-pride-month-rainbow-crepe-cake/", 
"/tag/baking-therapy/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/celebrate-pride-month-rainbow-crepe-cake/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/article/healthy-baking-recipes-when-bored-at-home/", 
"/tag/baking/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/article/healthy-baking-recipes-when-bored-at-home/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/warm-salted-caramel-lava-cakes/", 
"/tag/baking-therapy/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/warm-salted-caramel-lava-cakes/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/peanut-butter-vegan-mug-cake/", 
"/tag/vegan/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/peanut-butter-vegan-mug-cake/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/article/childhood-bakes-wall-of-bakers/", 
"/tag/wall-of-bakers/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/article/childhood-bakes-wall-of-bakers/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/orange-peel-campfire-brownies/", 
"/tag/summer/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/orange-peel-campfire-brownies/", 
"/search/brownies?page=2", "/", "https://www.instagram.com/foodnetworkca/", 
"https://www.facebook.com/foodnetworkcanada", "https://www.tiktok.com/@foodnetworkca", 
"/about-us/", "https://www.corusent.com/advertising/overview/", 
"https://www.corusent.com/", "/article/casting/", "https://www.corusent.com/privacy-policy/", 
"https://www.corusent.com/terms-of-use/", "https://www.corusent.com/terms-conditions/", 
"https://www.corusent.com/accessibility/", "/where-to-watch/", 
"/faq/", "//www.corusent.com/", "https://www.wnetwork.com/", 
"https://www.slice.ca", "https://showcase.ca", "https://www.hgtv.ca", 
"https://globaltv.com", "https://globalnews.ca/", "https://www.history.ca", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/brownies-reloaded/", "/tag/good-eats/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/brownies-reloaded/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/article/best-vegan-egg-substitutes/", 
"/tag/vegan/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/article/best-vegan-egg-substitutes/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/article/simple-swaps-for-healthier-baking-and-cooking/", 
"/tag/healthy-eating/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/article/simple-swaps-for-healthier-baking-and-cooking/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/good-for-you-no-bake-chocolate-crunch-brownies/", 
"/tag/vegan/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/good-for-you-no-bake-chocolate-crunch-brownies/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/article/anna-olsons-chocolate-recipes-easy-to-advanced/", 
"/tag/great-chocolate-showdown/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/article/anna-olsons-chocolate-recipes-easy-to-advanced/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/gluten-free-sweet-potato-beet-apple-pastry/", 
"/tag/healthy-eating/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/gluten-free-sweet-potato-beet-apple-pastry/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/article/reloaded-recipes-reinvent-classics/", 
"/tag/good-eats/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/article/reloaded-recipes-reinvent-classics/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/halloween-brownies/", "/tag/halloween/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/halloween-brownies/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/this-black-sesame-coconut-cream-pie-will-be-your-new-favourite-make-ahead-dessert/", 
"/tag/baking-therapy/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/this-black-sesame-coconut-cream-pie-will-be-your-new-favourite-make-ahead-dessert/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/article/sinful-chocolate-desserts/", 
"/tag/baking/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/article/sinful-chocolate-desserts/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/fudgy-keto-brownies/", "/tag/dessert/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/fudgy-keto-brownies/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/no-bake-key-lime-pie-icebox-cake/", 
"/tag/baking-therapy/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/no-bake-key-lime-pie-icebox-cake/", 
"/", "https://www.instagram.com/foodnetworkca/", "https://www.facebook.com/foodnetworkcanada", 
"https://www.tiktok.com/@foodnetworkca", "/about-us/", "https://www.corusent.com/advertising/overview/", 
"https://www.corusent.com/", "/article/casting/", "https://www.corusent.com/privacy-policy/", 
"https://www.corusent.com/terms-of-use/", "https://www.corusent.com/terms-conditions/", 
"https://www.corusent.com/accessibility/", "/where-to-watch/", 
"/faq/", "//www.corusent.com/", "https://www.wnetwork.com/", 
"https://www.slice.ca", "https://showcase.ca", "https://www.hgtv.ca", 
"https://globaltv.com", "https://globalnews.ca/", "https://www.history.ca", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/article/things-you-can-make-with-leftover-sourdough-starter/", 
"/tag/kitchen-tips/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/article/things-you-can-make-with-leftover-sourdough-starter/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/glazed-mini-brownies/", "/tag/the-pioneer-woman/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/glazed-mini-brownies/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/article/holiday-desserts-for-last-minute-guests/", 
"/tag/holidays/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/article/holiday-desserts-for-last-minute-guests/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/treat-mom-to-these-buttery-lemon-scones-with-a-tangy-lemon-curd/", 
"/tag/baking-therapy/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/treat-mom-to-these-buttery-lemon-scones-with-a-tangy-lemon-curd/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/mini-bagels-and-epic-blt-bagel-board-recipe/", 
"/tag/baking-therapy/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/mini-bagels-and-epic-blt-bagel-board-recipe/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/banana-upside-down-cake/", 
"/tag/baking-therapy/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/banana-upside-down-cake/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/gluten-free-coconut-flour-brownies/", 
"/tag/fruit/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/gluten-free-coconut-flour-brownies/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/article/best-baking-recipes/", "/tag/baking/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/article/best-baking-recipes/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/chocolate-and-coconut-pots-de-creme/", 
"/tag/baking/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/chocolate-and-coconut-pots-de-creme/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/halloween-cheesecake/", "/tag/halloween/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/halloween-cheesecake/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/strawberry-cheesecake-brownies/", 
"/tag/the-pioneer-woman/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/strawberry-cheesecake-brownies/", 
"https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/fudgy-raspberry-swirl-brownies/", 
"/tag/baking/", "https://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/fudgy-raspberry-swirl-brownies/", 
"/", "https://www.instagram.com/foodnetworkca/", "https://www.facebook.com/foodnetworkcanada", 
"https://www.tiktok.com/@foodnetworkca", "/about-us/", "https://www.corusent.com/advertising/overview/", 
"https://www.corusent.com/", "/article/casting/", "https://www.corusent.com/privacy-policy/", 
"https://www.corusent.com/terms-of-use/", "https://www.corusent.com/terms-conditions/", 
"https://www.corusent.com/accessibility/", "/where-to-watch/", 
"/faq/", "//www.corusent.com/", "https://www.wnetwork.com/", 
"https://www.slice.ca", "https://showcase.ca", "https://www.hgtv.ca", 
"https://globaltv.com", "https://globalnews.ca/", "https://www.history.ca"
)), row.names = c(NA, -175L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I have amended the question with the dput & specified some objects I am using.

Comment: Your data after the first filter doesn't have the rows matching remove.list i.e. try `dat %>% filter(grepl('gallery|article|tag', url_list))` it returns those, but if you subset with `brownies` first, then there are no intersects

Comment: Hmm, I am not following.For example, If I use `filter(!grepl("/tag/", url_list))` I expect it to only remove rows containing "/tag/". However instead it removes the entire thing.

Comment: Not clear about your comment.  If you want substring, you need `sub` or gsub or str_extract

Comment: I want to retain only the full URLs containing `brownies` and remove URLs from the list that contain specified words (e.g., remove.list). The remaining URLs are fed into a pipeline that scrapes the site for data.

Comment: Why not use `dat %>% filter(!grepl(remove.list, url_list) & grepl(query, url_list) ) %>% unique`

Comment: It results in nothing in the table, my original problem.

Comment: I get `dat %>% filter(!grepl(remove.list, url_list) & grepl(query, url_list) ) %>% unique %>% nrow#
[1] 13` i.e. 13 rows

Comment: Weird - I get `dat <- url_list %>%
  filter(!grepl('article|tag', url_list) & grepl(query, url_list)) %>% 
  unique()` `> nrow(dat)
[1] 0`

Comment: The structure you showed had column name `.`.  I changed it to `url_list` as column name assuming that it was a typo

Comment: Oh my gosh that was my problem from the beginning. The column got named . for some reason. Thank you for bearing with me!

Comment: Sometimes, when people post questions with a structure, we thiink that it is just a typo as part of creating a reproducible example

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I usually just use dput(df) to avoid any typos.